# If srand() takes 32-bit int... Why does rand() not return same?

Tags: c, random

Cross-platform, the limitation of standard `rand()` is that you can only rely on it to generate 16-bit `short`s... you can bitshift to create longer numbers from these, but it's an inconvenience.

Why is it that although `rand()` only *effectively* returns up to a 16-bit value, `srand()` *takes* 32-bit `int` to seed that same process?

Comment: Because in order to achieve better randomness, a PRNG can only return so many bits of its internal state. If it returned all the bits of the internal state, the output would be trivially predictable.

Comment: "rand() only effectively returns up to a 16-bit value" --> the return value of `rand()` is `[0...RAND_MAX]` which may be as small as 15 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `INT_MAX` (the implementation-defined maximum that an `int` supports) is not guaranteed to be greater than `32767` either.   Practically, that means an `int` is not guaranteed to be more than 16 bits (although the standard doesn't say that, it can be inferred that the value `32767` can be represented using 16 bits.

This means the basic premise of your question is wrong.   The standard requires that `srand()` accept an `int` seed, and that `rand()` returns an `int` value.

If a compiler supplies a 32-bit `int` (which is not required, but is permitted by the standard) then `srand()` will accept a 32-bit seed, and `rand()` will return a 32-bit value between `0` and `RAND_MAX`.

The decoupling of `INT_MAX` and `RAND_MAX` (i.e. the standard does not require them to be equal, but doesn't prevent it either) simply gives vendors freedom on how they implement `srand()` and `rand()`.   Different vendors then make different choices, for their own reasons (commercial, technical, etc).

Comment: "The standard requires that `srand()` accept an `int` seed" --> The standard's signature uses `unsigned` as in `void srand(unsigned int seed);`.  This _may_ not have as many different values as `int`, although `int/unsigned` commonly do have the same number of distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

The *range* of a PRNG is independent of its *period*. The *range* is the set of numbers it can return: a 16-bit PRNG returns only 16-bit numbers; that is, values 0..65535.

The *period* of a PRNG is how many times it can be called before its sequence repeats, and you generally want that to me much larger than the range--ideally you want that to be infinite, but practically speaking we are limited by the amount of memory in the computer.

The period of a PRNG is limited by the size of its internal state. If that internal state is, say, 32 bits, then the PRNG's period can be no longer than 4 billion or so, and there are only 4 billion different seeds. Something like Mersenne Twister has an internal state of over 2400 bytes, and therefore an insanely large period, and can be seeded with all of those 2400+ bytes if you want.

Comment: The _period_ is limited the internal state of the PRNG, something not specified in C.  Only up to `UINT_MAX+1` seeds can be applied with `srand(unsigned)`, regardless of the internal state size.